# SELECT с блокировкой FOR UPDATE

Tags: mysql, innodb

Имеется запрос такого вида:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table`
WHERE `index1` = :index1
  AND `index2` = :index2
  AND `index3` = :index3
  AND `index4` = :index4
FOR UPDATE
```

.. где `id` - это первичный ключ, а `indexN` - это колонки с индексами.

Далее, на основании существования `id` должна производиться либо вставка новой строки `INSERT`, либо её обновление `UPDATE`.

Первый вопрос: будут ли операцией `FOR UPDATE` заблокированы на изменение другие строки, в которых часть индексов `indexN` будет совпадать по значению, указанному в `WHERE`?

И второй вопрос: является ли операция `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` эффективнее обозначенной выше, если предполагается, что `INSERT` - единовременная, тогда как последующих `UPDATE` - будет подавляющее большинство?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос 1: Нет. Блокируются только отобранные записи.

Вопрос 2: Да, несомненно.